# NFS mount with file locking not possible any more after move to new subnet: statd timed out, lockd cannot monitor

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, subnet

I'm operating an Ubuntu 10.04 NFS Server with LDAP user authentication on a virtual machine in Subnet A. The server exports the users home directories with nfs v3 to ubuntu clients in subnets B and C. The server has other services runing, that shouldn't matter for my problem at the moment. Everything worked fine for several years.

Now we moved to a new building and got a new subnet D (hosts in subnet B and C became the new subnet D). Furthermore, the connection to the computing center, where my virtual servers are hosted, has now one kilometer of a cable from a commercial provider in between and has a smaller bandwidth. These are the only two things that have changed to my knowledge.

The problem is now, that I can only make working connections/mounts from the clients by using the `nolock` option. If this option is not provided, I get the following message on the server in `/var/log/syslog`

```
kernel: [11457.902470] statd: server rpc.statd not responding, timed out
kernel: [11457.902481] lockd: cannot monitor notos
```

and on clients with home mounted without the nolock option the users can not open any programs with a gui that tries to set file locks (google-chrome,...) or can even not log in (since locking is required as well).

On the first days after the move, when we only had half of the clients in the new subnet, I was not aware of the problem or it hasn't even been there.

Beside many other things, I tried what is described in [this launchpad bug description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1089941). I thought the commercial provider might not be multicast able. But it didn't have any effect.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use locks with NFS (and one really should!), your server must provide a RPC server where the clients can connect to. This is for coordinating locks.

Verify that the RPC server is running. If so, there must be something else blocking the communication between your clients and the RPC server. Since you seem to have general network connectivity, there must be a firewall (either on the server or the client itself, or somewhere between your clients and the server) blocking the connection attempts.

Comment: on the server i get:  
vuvu:~$ ps aux | grep rpc  
root       881  0.0  0.0      0     0 ? D    07:35   0:00 [rpciod/0]
root       882  0.0  0.0      0     0 ? S    07:35   0:00 [rpciod/1]
root       937  0.0  0.0  23048   596 ? Ss   07:35   0:00 rpc.idmapd
root      1144  0.1  0.0  59664  2468 ? Ss   07:35   0:26 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd --manage-gids
root      1391  0.0  0.0  10828   644 ? Ss   07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/rpc.rquotad
statd     2193  0.0  0.0  16896  1052 ? Ss   09:45   0:00 rpc.statd -L
so it seems, rpc is running.

Comment: Yup. Now proceed with the 'net.

Comment: From client to server, the tcp-ports of the services reported by rpcinfo -p are open. The udp ones are open for rpcbind and nfs and open|filtered for rquotad, nlockmgr, mountd, and status. For filtering rules I need to contact the computing center, I guess.

Comment: You can gain more confidence on wether the ports are open by running nmap with the -sV option.

Comment: Ok, I just used -sU -p for udp and -p for tcp. Now I see, all are opened for rpcbind.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It had nothing to do with the setup of the network. Two clients recently added are running with a kernel version 3.8. This kernel seems to have a bug in the lockd, which causes the the server lockd to crash. After downgrading the kernel of these clients to 3.2, everything works as before.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry in `/etc/services` like so:

```
sunrpc                  111/tcp         rpcbind # SUN Remote Procedure Call
sunrpc                  111/udp         rpcbind # SUN Remote Procedure Call
```